# Spring AMQP AcknowledgeMode.AUTO works slow

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a producer which sends to RabbitMQ 20 messages per second and also I have a consumer, which should receive message with the same speed as they are produced.

There are some conditions I have to implement:

1. Produce and consume 20 messages per second.
2. Save the producing order.
3. The messages shouldn't be lost (that's why I use AcknowledgeMode.AUTO).

When I use Spring AMQP realization (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit), my consumer processes maximum 6 messages per second. But if I use the native AMQP library (com.rabbitmq.client) it does all 20 messages per second with both ack - auto and manual.

**The question is:**

Why Spring implementation in Consumer case works so slow and how can I fix this?

*If I set prefetchCount(20) it works as needed, but I can't use prefetch because it can break the order in a reject case.*

Spring amqp:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitMqServer);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitMqUsername);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitMqPassword);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

...

```
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer createContainer(Queue queue, Receiver receiver, AcknowledgeMode acknowledgeMode) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer persistentListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    persistentListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    persistentListenerContainer.setQueues(queue);
    persistentListenerContainer.setMessageListener(receiver);
    persistentListenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return persistentListenerContainer;
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {saveToDb}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AMQP (before 2.0) defaults prefetch to 1 which, as you say, guarantees order even after a rejection.

The native client applies no `basicQos()` by default which effectively means it has infinite prefetch.

So you are not comparing apples and apples.

Try `channel.basicQos(1)` with the native client and you should see similar results to the default spring amqp setup.

**EDIT**

When comparing apples with apples, I get similar results with/without the framework...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So47995535Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47995535Application.class, args).close();
    }

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(100);

    private int nativeCount;

    private int rlCount;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ConnectionFactory factory, RabbitTemplate template,
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "foo" + i);
            }
            container.start();
            Connection conn = factory.createConnection();
            Channel channel = conn.createChannel(false);
            channel.basicQos(1);
            channel.basicConsume("foo", new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, BasicProperties properties,
                        byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("native " + new String(body));
                    channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
                    nativeCount++;
                    latch.countDown();
                }

            });
            latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Native: " + this.nativeCount + " LC: " + this.rlCount);
            channel.close();
            conn.close();
            container.stop();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        container.setPrefetchCount(1);
        container.setAutoStartup(false);
        container.setMessageListener((MessageListener) m -> {
            System.out.println("LC " + new String(m.getBody()));
            this.rlCount++;
            this.latch.countDown();
        });
        return container;
    }

}
```

and

```
Native: 50 LC: 50
```

Comment: When using `basicQos(1)`, I get the same results either way - see my edit.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the explanation. As far as I understood, it's impossible  to fulfil all three my condition speed-reliability-order, right?

Comment: Not unless you can speed up your processing, or your network. With my test (doing no work at all in the listener except incrementing an int and counting down a latch), with the broker on `localhost` I can achieve > 4000 messages/second, even with prefetch = 1. So I would advise you to look at the efficiency of your listener code.